# Printing and replacing multiple lines

Tags: python, list

I have a list with some numbers, for example:

`list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

And need my output to be:

```
0
1
2
```

And then replace the output in the terminal to be:

```
1
2
3
```

And so on. I tried using `print()` with `\r` key to replace, but since i need to print multiple lines, it doesn't replace, and i get the following as an output:

```
0
1
2
1
2
3
2
3
4
```

I think i need something to limit the amount of lines shown, but i can't make it work.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which terminal you're using, since commands for clearing the terminal can vary across platforms &c.

Comment: I am using GNOME Terminal 3.36.2, on Linux Mint.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but what determines the output? Is it each sub-sequence of 3 elements?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Comment: The idea is to print the first three elements of the list, and after each time it has printed the first three, pop the first one (list[0]), and then repeat.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely check it out. Sorry if this question was not asked in a good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your terminal supports it, you can use the [VT100 escape sequence](https://www.cse.psu.edu/%7Ekxc104/class/cse472/09s/hw/hw7/vt100ansi.htm) `<ESC>[{COUNT}A`, for example:

```
n = 3
move_cursor_vt100 = f'\x1b[{n+1}A'

L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(len(L)-n+1):
    if i != 0:
        print(move_cursor_vt100)
    sub = L[i:i+n]
    for x in sub:
        print(x)
```

Although, this doesn't clear the lines. So if you were to have `L = [90, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, the first line would be `90`, then `10`, then `20`. You can use `<ESC>[2K` to clear a line.

Comment: I will take a look on this VT100 thing, thanks for the suggestion. This code does exactly what i wanted, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system('cls||clear')
```

I used cls||clear because it may vary across platforms like @Imjohns3 said